# get a Json value without string key - Java JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

It' easy to get a value from JSON when you have the string key, but what if you have situation like that:

```
{
  "images":["URL1"]
}
```

And array and no key inside? I use this code:

```
JSONArray imagesArr = propertiesjsonObject.getJSONArray("images");
for (int y=0; i<imagesArr.length(); y++)
{
  JSONObject imagesJsonObject = imagesArr.getJSONObject(y);
  String str_image_url = imagesJsonObject.get("HOW TO GET THE VALUES HERE?");
}
```

Propably it's ultra easy. Sorry to ask but I could not find proper example. PS. I use: import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

PS2: For now there is only one element in array, but in future I suppouse there might be more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with this:

```
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray imagesArr = propertiesjsonObject.getJSONArray("images");
for (int i = 0; i < imagesArr.length(); i++) {
    String str_image_url = imagesArr.getString(i);
    urls.add(str_image_url);
}
```

urls is an array with all the url you got

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it's Ultra easy :) . Thanx. +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str_image_url = imagesArr.getString(0);//you specify position in array here
```